# DIDISOFT - OPEN PGP Null pointer exception on decrypt

Tags: c#, pgp

I am using OpenPGP from didisoft to encrypt and decrypt files. I have an encrypted file and the private key corresponding to the encryption key. But when I try to use the DecryptFile () method, I get a null pointer exception.. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.
Code:

```
public void decryptFile(string filename, string destPath)

string password = "xxx";
                string encFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + filename;
                string keyFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DecryptKeyFile"].ToString();
                PGPLib pgpDecrypter = new PGPLib();
                File.Create(destPath + filename);
                string a = pgpDecrypter.DecryptFile(encFile, keyFile, password, destPath+filename);  // I get the error on this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This support request has been handled on the official [DidiSoft support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/didisoft_forum/GnPCGkh4Jh8)

The main support channel for DidiSoft products is by email to support@didisoft.com and has a  guaranteed same day response for support requests issued till 8:00 PM GMT / 3:00 PM CST

Additional methods of support can be found at the [DidiSoft support information page](http://didisoft.com/support/).

Comment: Thank you. Quick and great support. Thumbs up guys.Thanks